# MySQL convert datetime to unixtime?

Tags: mysql, unix-timestamp

I have a column with the DATETIME format and I would like to convert it to UNIXTIME in the database. What kind of query would that be?

I know how to convert from UNIXTIME to DATETIME, but I've never done the reverse. I've used FROM_UNIXTIME, is there no TO_UNIXTIME?

Answer (score 13):

It's [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp).  This will take a properly formatted datetime as an argument.

Comment: Yes, that's right sorry that's what I meant. It's just I don't know the proper query to be used.

Comment: If you want milliseconds though be sure to multiply with 1000.

Answer (score 5):

It's okay, I figured it out.

I had 'article_date' for the original column.
I created 'new_date' for the new column.

Then I did:

```
UPDATE news SET new_date = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(article_date)
```